# Using **kwargs to assign dictionary keys + values to a class instance

Tags: python, dictionary, initialization, instance, keyword-argument

I'm trying to use `**kwargs` to create a dictionary inside an instance of a class. I want to hand my Book class two required variables(`title` and `author`) as well as a number of optional key/value pairs, and have it create an internal dictionary holding those keys and values. Here is my code:

```
class Book:
    
    def __init__(self, title, author, **kwargs):

        self.info = {
            'title': title,
            'author': author,
        }
```

For example, I'd like to hand Book an argument like `year='1961'` and have it set up a key/value pair (`'year': '1961'`). Up until now I've been using `if/else` statements for this, but that seems inefficient and ugly. Can I use `**kwargs` to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kwargs` can be treated as a dictionary and you can merge the two sets of data few different ways [depending on your python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona).

### 3.9+:

```py
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title, author, **kwargs):
        self.info = {
            'title': title,
            'author': author,
        } | kwargs
```

### 3.5+:

```py
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title, author, **kwargs):
        self.info = {
            'title': title,
            'author': author,
            **kwargs}
```

### <3.4:

```py
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title, author, **kwargs):
        self.info = {
            'title': title,
            'author': author,
        }
        self.info.update(kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can used kwargs, I think you are looking for the following code:

```
class Book:

    def __init__(self, title, author, **kwargs):

        self.info = {
            'title': title,
            'author': author,
        }

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            self.info[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just figured it out.

```
class Book:
    
    def __init__(self, title, author, **kwargs):

        self.info = {
            'title': title,
            'author': author,
        }

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            self.info[key] = value
```

This should have been obvious in retrospect